# Characteristic function and Fourier transform for a discrete random variable!

Tags: probability, fourier-transform, characteristic-function

Let $\phi_{x}(t)= E [ e^{itx}]$ be the **characteristic function**

If X is a continuous random variable, then:

$\phi_{x}(t)= E [ e^{itx}] = \int e^{itx} f(x)dx$ (being $f(x)$ the probability density function of x)

If X is a discrete random variable, then:

$\phi_{x}(t)= E [ e^{itx}] = \sum_{k} e^{itx_{k}} p(x_{k})$ (being $p(x)$ the probability mass function of x)

To be general Fourier transform can be define as (Ref: https://www.johndcook.com/blog/fourier-theorems/):

$F(s)=\frac{1}{A}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{iBst}f(t)dt$

The choices that are found in practice are:

$A=\sqrt{2\pi}, B=\pm 1;$
$A=1, B=\pm 2\pi;$
$A=1, B=\pm 1$

Choosing A=1 and B=1 to relate it to the characteristic function, the inverse Fourier transform is:

$f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ist}F(s)ds$

In continuous case:

$\phi_{x}(t) = \int e^{itx} f(x)dx \rightarrow f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ixt}\phi_{x}(t)dt$

That is the utility of the characteristic function, it allows me to know the probability function

But in the discrete case I get problems:

If discrete Fourier transform (DFT) is :

$F(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{-2\pi sn/N}f(n)$

The inverse DFT is:

$f(t)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} e^{2\pi sn/N}F(s)$

So, Would the "inverse" characteristic function be

$\phi_{x}(t) = \sum_{k} e^{itx_{k}} p(x_{k}) \rightarrow P(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi N}\sum_{k} e^{-ixt_{k}}\phi_{x}(t_{n})$ ?

So if FT can have different definitions for the continuous case. What happen with the discrete case? How many definitions are?

Answer (score 2):

For the discrete case, you need to look at [DTFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20discrete%2Dtime,samples%20of%20a%20continuous%20function.), not DFT. N-point DFT assumes that the underlying function is periodic, which is not the case for probability mass functions. You can then apply similar logic for [inverse transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform#/Inverse_transform):

$$\phi_{x}(t)= E [ e^{itx}] = \sum_{k} e^{itx_{k}} p(x_{k})\rightarrow p(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-ixt}\phi_x(t)dt$$

For example, characteristic function for Bernouilli RV is $\phi_x(t)=1-p+pe^{it}$. Applying the formula yields the following:

$$\begin{align}p(x)&={1\over 2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-ixt} (1-p+pe^{it})dt\\&=(1-p){1\over 2\pi}\underbrace{\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-itx}dt}_{2\pi\delta_x} + p\frac{1}{2\pi}\underbrace{\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-it(x-1)}dt}_{2\pi\delta_{x-1}}\\&=(1-p)\delta_x+p\delta_{x-1}\end{align}$$

where $\delta_x$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#:%7E:text=where%20the%20Kronecker%20delta%20%CE%B4,compactly%20expressing%20its%20definition%20above.) function, i.e. it's $1$ if $x=0$, and $0$ otherwise.

This is from Fourier transform perspective. [Probability theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#/Inversion_formulae) has its own principled way of calculating inverses.

Comment: +1 and can you provide more details may be with an example?

Comment: @HaitaoDu great advice. I've added an example for Bernoulli RV.

Comment: @gunes Why is the upper limit of the integral 2$\pi$?

Also I know I can use Stieltjes integral as $F(b)-F(a)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{ e^{-itb}- e^{-ita}}{-it}f(t)dt$ 
But if $F_{x}(x)=P(X\leq x) = \sum_{x_{i} \leq x} P(X=x_{i}) = \sum_{x_{i} \leq x} p(x_{i})$ How do you integrate it and put inside the integral?

Comment: @gunus And also I think $\delta_{x}$ is Dirac delta no Kronecker delta

Comment: It's inverse DTFT, any $2\pi$ range would be ok. It's single argument version of kronecker delta. And it's equivalent to discrete version of dirac delta, $\delta[n]$

Comment: @gunes Do you have some lecture, books or videos about that topic that you can suggest me? it would be appreciated.

Comment: for a probability theory treatment, this source seems good: https://statweb.stanford.edu/~adembo/stat-310b/lnotes.pdf for fourier transform review, I strongly recommend Oppenheim

Comment: @gunes Do you have more examples like Bernouilli? What happen with a mixed case?

Comment: PDFs for mixed RVs typically include continuous dirac delta function, which the Continuous Time Fourier Transform can operate on. I didn't take the example from some book or notes, I've just taken the formula for characteristic function from the wikipedia page, and applied inverse DTFT to it. You can try others and see if you can come up with the PMF. If you can't, you can ask it in this forum but make sure to ask a separate question for it.